# Wordpress multiple custom post type archive page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have this code placed in function.php which was working fine when I used it to set the archive page for 1 set of custom post type.

```
// custom type: Blogs
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'blogs', 
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'blogs' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'blog' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

So when I wanted to add in a new post ype with an archive page, I did this

```
// custom type: Blogs
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'blogs', 
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'blogs' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'blog' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
register_post_type( 'events', 
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'events' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'event' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

which returned me an error on the newly added post-type.

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: @FluffyKitten The events archive page could not be found, but the blogs' archive page was still available

Comment: So you got a 404 error, you mean? Do you re-save permalinks after adding the code?